# Ubuntu Default language midnight commander

Tags: ubuntu, mc

Please help me to change default language in `midnight commander` from ru to en, now, to start `mc` in english i have to write `LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc` in terminal, but it's too long, i want `mc` in english by `mc` ty:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [ru.stackoverflow.com in russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455931/182317)

Try to make alias like:

```
alias mc='LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc'
```

Author says not a best way, but helped

Also you need  `source ~./bashrc` or `logout` to apply changes

Comment: It's always a good idea to append `$*` at the end of an alias, i.e. — `alias mc='LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc $*'` in case you want to pass the arguments to the process, then it will still work as expected for example when you call `mc ~/bin`.

Comment: @ccpizza No need for that `$*`, aliases forward the arguments anyway. And even if they didn't, `"$@"` (double quotes and dollar-at) would be the only correct way of forwarding them even in presence of embedded spaces.

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled over this thread trying to change my Midnight Commander on macOS Sierra away from French and since macOS is unix and since using an alias did not really suit me, this is what I added to my ~/.bashrc:

```
export LANG="en_EN.UTF-8"
```

then I sourced .bashrc and all was well (i.e. ran `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal).

Please note that this might affect other applications as well. But I have not discovered any - in any case that is exactly what I want. Further note that I have only tested this on a mac, yet it should work just as well on Ubuntu or other *nix's.

Answer (score 0):

This is good answer, yet there's no clear reason why MC uses other than English in my case. I noticed it happens whenever I have another language in Systems Preferences -> Language & Region -> Preferred languages, even if English is set to Primary.